# Accessing TextView inside a fragment is giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, textview

A fragment is defined as follows. I am trying to set Text of `positionTextView`.

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    private TextView positionTextView,fragment2TextView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment2, container, false);
        positionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.positionTextView);
        fragment2TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment2TextView);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"OnCreateView",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return  view;

    }

    public void setContentOfTextView( int position) {
        positionTextView.setText(Integer.toString(position));
    }
}
```

And in the `MainActivity`, I am adding the `Fragment2` as follows.

```
@Override
public void fragmentRespond(int index) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    transaction.add(R.id.group2,fragment2,"fragment2");
    transaction.commit();
    transaction.addToBackStack("fragment2");
    fragment2.setContentOfTextView(index);
}
```

I have the `fragmentRespond` function in another fragment which contains a `ListView`. The `ListView`'s `onItemClickListener` calls this function, i.e, `fragmentRespond(int index)`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] quotes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quotes);
    CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getContext(),quotes,null);
    listView.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            fragmentCommunicator.fragmentRespond(position);
        }
    });
}
```

And I am getting the following error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Any suggestions regarding this problem or improving the coding style is very well appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an NPE because the view of the `Fragment` was not yet loaded when you are trying to set the text using the `setContentOfTextView` function from your activity.

The views in your fragment needs to be inflated first, in order to load something in it. Hence, you should do this in your fragment's `onCreateView` function.

About passing the information from your activity - you can easily do that using a `Bundle` passed to your fragment while launching it from your activity.

Here's how you can do that.

In your activity, pass the data using a `Bundle` while launching your fragment.

```
@Override
public void fragmentRespond(int index) {

    // Prepare the bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("index", index);

    FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    fragment2.setArguments(bundle); // Set the arguments here to be passed on to your fragment while loading.

    transaction.add(R.id.group2,fragment2, "fragment2");
    transaction.commit();
    transaction.addToBackStack("fragment2");
}
```

And in your fragment, get the desired data from that `Bundle` and load it into your `TextView`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment2, container, false);
    positionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.positionTextView);
    fragment2TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment2TextView);

    // Load the information in your TextView here
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("index")) {
        setContentOfTextView(args.getInt("index"));
    }

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"OnCreateView",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return  view;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will give it a try.

Comment: Just commenting, but great answer!

Comment: Thanks! @GauravMall

Comment: Yes ,It successfully overcame the NPE.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ReazMurshed.

Comment: Cool. Glad to know that I could help!